# Gramm matlab coloring points but not lines

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting some values with geom_point in [gramm](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54465-gramm-complete-data-visualization-toolbox-ggplot2-r-like#overview_tab). The x-axis is trials within a session and I'm also plotting a line (geom_line) to connect the dots. My problem is that I'm trying to color the dots of the plot without having the lines also follow this color and thus connecting my dots in a weird way and messing up with the numbers of trials (see screenshot below).

```
clear g
n=1;
m=1;
g(n,m) = gramm('x',a.TrialsInBlock,'y',a.RT, 'color', a.feedback, 'subset', a.blockNumbered==1)
g(n,m).geom_line();
g(n,m).geom_point();
g(n,m).set_names('x','TrialNumber','y','RT','color','Feedback');
g(n,m).set_title('RT');
figure('Position',[191.5000 358 2153 967]);
g.draw();
```

[image: y axis is reaction times, x axis is trial number and I wan to color the dots but not connected by feedback]

Comment: It appear that [`geom_line`](https://viewer.mathworks.com/?viewer=plain_code&url=https%3A%2F%2Fch.mathworks.com%2Fmatlabcentral%2Fmlc-downloads%2Fdownloads%2F70a0cf59-249f-4dd6-993e-8c867a616963%2Fc5d1b70a-990c-43ee-8a26-7a4feeba83c2%2Ffiles%2F%40gramm%2Fgeom_line.m&embed=web) passes all arguments beyond the first two directly on to its contained call to [`patch()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html). You could try passing name-value pairs as `'EdgeColor','black','FaceColor','none'`.

Comment: I ran this ```g(n,m).geom_line('EdgeColor','black','FaceColor','none')``` within the plot and it's giving me error: Error using gramm/geom_line (line 10)
'EdgeColor' is not a recognized parameter. For a list of valid name-value pair arguments, see the documentation for this function.

Comment: Alternatively you could do it yourself by calling `fig = gcf`, i.e. grabbing a figure handle (shows up as a struct of a big list of property names), then figuring out which of its children is your line, which in turn will have the properties `EdgeColor` and `FaceColor`, which you can set to whatever colour-triplet you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this, first I plot the data without grouping it and then I update that same plot with colors based on a group.

```
clear g
n=1;
m=1;
g(n,m) = gramm('x',a.TrialsInBlock,'y',a.RT, 'column', a.blockNumbered);
g(n,m).facet_wrap(a.blockNumbered);
g(n,m).geom_line();
g(1,1).set_color_options('map', [0 0 0]);
g(n,m).set_names('x','TrialNumber','y','RT');
g(n,m).set_title('RT');
figure('Position',[191.5000 358 2153 967]);
%g.draw(); 


g(1,1).update('color',a.feedback);
g(1,1).set_color_options('map', 'spring');
g(n,m).geom_point();
g.draw();
```